# Filter by number in Vue.js

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs2

I am starting in vue.
I have an input that filters by the name of the store, the name of the store is collected through a json where it also has the id_store, but the id_store is a number.
How can I also filter by store_id?

```js
 computed: {
    filteredTiendas: function() {
      return Object.values(
        this.items
      ).filter(item => {
        return item.desc_store.match(this.search);
      });
    },
    searchUp: {
      get() {
        return this.search.toLowerCase();
      },
      set(search) {
        this.search = search.toUpperCase();
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```css
[
{
"id_store": 2,
"desc_store": "ALBORAYA",
"type_store": "GSB"
},
{
"id_store": 4,
"desc_store": "LAS ROZAS",
"type_store": "GSB"
},
{
"id_store": 5,
"desc_store": "UTEBO",
"type_store": "GSB"
}
]
```

```html
<div class="input-icon-wrap">
  <span class="input-icon"><img src="../../iconos/icon/loupe@3x.svg" alt=""></span>
  <input v-model="searchUp" placeholder="Busca tu tienda" class="input-with-icon" id="form-name">
</div>  
    </div>
    <div class="todastiendas">
    <div v-for="(item, i) in filteredTiendas" :key="i">
      <router-link :to="{name: 'secciones', params: { id: item.desc_store, id1: item.id_store  }}">
        <div class="tiendas">
            <span>{{item.id_store}}</span>
          <h1>{{ item.desc_store.toLowerCase()}}</h1>
          <img src="../../iconos/icon/chevron/right@3x.svg" alt />
        </div>
      </router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `item.id_store.toString().match(this.search)`?

Comment: if it works well, and how do I get the two filters to work at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update `filter()` method like:

```
.filter(({desc_store, id_store}) => {
   return desc_store.match(this.search) || id_store.toString().match(this.search);
});
```